# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

When i compile the following code , it works fine , but in console i get error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin(){
   myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "myWindow");
}


function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
var myWindow;

function openWin(){


    myWindow = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/", "myWindow");
 
}


function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();

}
```

i tried to call the above js file externally also, i get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to click `Open "myWindow"` button before clicking the other one, because that is when the variable myWindow gets initial value.

You should check if window has been opened before trying to close it:

```
function closeWin() {
    if(myWindow){
        myWindow.close();
    }
}
```

If `myWindow` is not set, you just do nothing (as there is nothing to be closed, right?).

Comment: i tried your example but still getting error., i'm sharing you the link from were i got this idea http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close

Comment: still getting error check console in browser i'm using chrome error is                                                                                                        Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/0r0Lgawo/show/' from frame with URL 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/0r0Lgawo/show/'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.
closeWin @ fiddle.jshell.net/:44